# statement in jQuery without semicolon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a statement like below ,

```
url : "expand.do?parentID=" + node.id,
```

This statement is a part of jQuery tree plugin that I am using.Now, it is not allowing me to put semi colon in the end of this statement and I need to put it in If condition to call action based on some value. If I use statement like this only then it works fine.

Comment: It is not considered as a statement. It is a part of JSON Object. Object will not allow you to put semi colon inside it.

Comment: Thanks Santosh , I dont know much about JSON. I will search on it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't a statement, it's a *property initializer*, presumably followed by other property initializers. It sounds like you're using them in an argument being passed to a function, e.g.:

```
someFunctionCall({
    prop1: "value 1",
    prop2: "value 2"
});
```

Property initializers are separated from subsequent property initializers with commas, not semicolons, which is why adding a semicolon won't work.

The right-hand side of a property initializer is an *expression*. If you need to do conditional logic in that expression, you can use the conditional operator (`? :`), e.g.:

```
someFunctionCall({
    prop1: someCondition ? "value 1" : "value 2",
    prop2: "..."
});
```

If you need to do something more complex than you can readily do in an expression, or if you need to access those properties in subsequent logic, you can split things up:

```
var params = {
    prop2: "..."
};
if (someCondition) {
    params.prop1 = "value 1";
} else {
    params.prop1 = "value 2";
}
// and/or
if (params.prop2 === "foo") {
    // ....
}
someFunctionCall(params);
```

Comment: Thank you , second approach helped :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case "url" is a key inside an object. Based on the comma you have there is looks there are multiple keys in this object.

```
var foo = { url : "expand.do?parentID=" + node.id, bar: "blah"}
```

If you want to use the value of url in an IF statement then

```
if(foo.url){ 
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
{url : getURL(node),
```

and

```
function getURL(node){
    if (node.something == 'something'){
     var node_id = node.id
    }else
    {
     var node_id = (node.id + 22)
    }
    return "expand.do?parentID=" + node_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely some part of JSON. JSON syntax looks like this:

```
{url : "expand.do?parentID=" + node.id}
```

Usually, there are more elements:

```
{
    hello: 'world',
    'I can even have spaces and Funny characters: 1 * 1 = 2 and PI: π': '3.14159265359'
}
```

However, JSON is really just an object.

This means that whatever JSON you have is really just an Object.

Comment: *"This is most likely some part of JSON"* Clearly not, JSON doesn't have a `+` operator. *"JSON syntax looks like this"* No, it doesn't, not in several ways. You're confusing [JSON](http://json.org) with JavaScript object initializer syntax. JSON is a strict *subset* of JavaScript literal value syntax, used for data exchange. If you're writing source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.